# What are the u's when I use json.loads?

Tags: python, json, encode

I've been writing a Python script to parse JSON information from the Soundcloud API, and I was just wondering what the "u"'s are when I use json.loads( val ) and how to store the JSON information to an object without the u's?

i.e. why are there u's in this:

```
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
[u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

See the "Decoding JSON" section here to understand what I mean further:

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Comment: Another helpful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940272/python-json-loads-returns-items-prefixing-with-u

Answer (score 15):

Unicode strings. See the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings).

> In Python source code, Unicode literals are written as strings prefixed with the ‘u’ or ‘U’ character: u'abcdefghijk'.
>
> — [Unicode Literals in Python Source Code](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

Answer (score 7):

the `u'`s are there to indicate that a Unicode string is supposed to be created.

It sucks that `json.dump` converts strings to unicode strings and leaves no trace of having done that, because then `json.load` can't convert back.

To convert to string objects, use [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/):

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
>>> ['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

But careful! If for some reason you `json.dump`ed an object containing object strings and unicode strings, `yaml` will load everything as object strings (though that's `json.dump`'s fault really)