# PHP json_encode to Python Command Line Argument - Funky characters

Tags: php, python, json, string, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the u’s when I use json.loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200962/what-are-the-us-when-i-use-json-loads)

Attempting to encode some string data into json in PHP via json_encode and pass it to my python script on the same server:

This data's going to contain quotes, and will have an embedded array full of strings of urls.

```
$data =array("test.com", array("http://google.com", "http://cnn.com"), "ASDASDASD");
$jsonified = json_encode($data);
shell_exec("python /path_to_script/script.py '".$jsonified."'");
```

which will hopefully run the script with the data as it's first argument.

Right now, I'm kinda rolling with just making sure it can load into a thing properly:

```
import json
import sys

encoded = sys.argv[1]
print "ENCODED: ", encoded

decoded = json.loads(encoded)
print "DECODED: ", decoded
```

and I'm calling it this way:

```
~$ python json-test.py '["test.com", ["http://www.google.com", "http://cnn.com"], "ASDASDASDASD"]'
ENCODED: ["test.com",["http://www.google.com", "http://cnn.com"], "ASDASDASDASD"]
DECODED: [u'test.com', [u'http://www.google.com', u'http://cnn.com'], u'ASDASDASDASD']
```

What's with the 'u's? Also am I correct in hoping this will somehow go together smoothly?

Comment: the `u` simply means those are unicode strings

Comment: So I'd have to, like decoded.encode('utf-8') or something?

Comment: Are you sure you have no better way of passing data than as an argument on the command line? I am skeptical of utf-8 surviving through a trip to the shell and back. What about piping your input through stdout/stdin, a named pipe, a file, or communicating through a database, to name just a few options here.

Comment: @Fal-Cone, most likely you don't have to do anything, but it depends on what you plan to do with the string. Unicode is what you want--it only seems strange to you because you're used to PHP.

Comment: @Fal-Cone - that depends on what you need to do with the strings. Pleas read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) before blindly trying to decode/encode strings.

Comment: Just trying to turn them into python strings.

Comment: @Fal-Cone a "string of bytes" (e.g. utf-8) is not the same as "a string of unicode characters". You have a python unicode string, decoded from utf-8. You had better have a good reason to encode it again, like writing it to a file or something.

Comment: I'm not being a stickler for encoding, I just want the data I'm passing through the command line to come out as normal python strings/arrays of strings intact and able to be used for python-stuff, and don't really have much of a willingness to stash the data in a file or in a database somewhere else when I can just pipe it directly to the script via command line. (I mean, I could pass the strings as individual arguments, but the possibility of an array terrifies me)

Comment: What makes "u" funky? I say "漢" has more funkfactor :)