# Convert unicode json to normal json in python

Tags: python, json, unicode

I got the following json: `{u'a': u'aValue', u'b': u'bValue', u'c': u'cValue'}` by doing `request.json` in my python code. Now, I want to convert the unicode json to normal json, something which should like this: `{"a": "aValue", "b": "bValue", "c": "cValue"}`. How do I get this done, without having to do any manual replacements? Please help.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Python: json.loads returns items prefixing with 'u'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13940272)

Comment: Whty is this bothering you?

Comment: Has been asked many times, Did you research? [How to get string objects instead of Unicode ones from JSON in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/956867)

Answer (score 13):

{u'a': u'aValue', u'b': u'bValue', u'c': u'cValue'} is a dictionary which you are calling as unicode json. Now, in your language if you want a regular json from this then just do something like this:

```
x={u'a': u'aValue', u'b': u'bValue', u'c': u'cValue'}
y=json.dumps(x)
print y
```

The output will be {"a": "aValue", "c": "cValue", "b": "bValue"}

Comment: Json.dumps does not return a dictionary. It only converts it into a string.

Comment: don't forget `import json`

Answer (score 8):

For python 2.x

```
import yaml
import json
json_data = yaml.load(json.dumps(request.json()))
```

Now this json_data can be used as a json and can have list of json as well.

Comment: yamal.load() depricated.
https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to encode all of the keys and values as ascii like this:

```
dict([(k.encode('ascii','ignore'), v.encode('ascii','ignore')) for k, v in dct.items()])
```

Note: There generally isn't much benefit to not having your data in unicode, so unless you have a specific reason not to have it in unicode, then I would leave it.

Answer (score 0):

A library available in PyPi may be helpful, see: [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/).

It is intended to transform European characters with diacriticals (accents) to their base ASCII characters, but it does just as well when the unicode character is already in the ASCII range.

```
from unicode import unidecode

def fUnUn(sOrU):
    return unidecode(sOrU).encode('ascii') if type(sOrU) is unicode else sOrU

sASCII = fUnUn(u'ASCII')
```