# Json library in python StringIO parsing?

Tags: python, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just want to ask something about json and python.

If I'm correct, loading a StringIO to json would result to it having a `u'`.

for example, in the json library:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> io = StringIO('["streaming API"]')
>>> json.load(io)
```

results to

```
[u'streaming API']
```

so how do I parse this data? in order for me to sort a data 
that looks like this? I have this data I want to parse.

> {u'brix': {u'Nov 29, 2017 11:20:15 PM': {u'Checklist': {u'Coffee tray
>   with 3 coffee sticks, 3 creamer, 3 white sugar, 3 brown sugar, 1 equal
>   or sweetener, 3 lipton tea, 2 mineral water, 3 cocktail napkin ?':
>   u'No', u'Luggage bench fabric top is clean': u'No', u'1 facial tissue
>   in a tissue box': u'No', u'Towel Reminder': u'No', u'1 pringles, 1
>   cashew nut, 1 cup noodles (placed in the coffee tray on the writing
>   desk)?': u'No',

After reading a bit about json I found out that this may be a StringIO instead of a json. It was silly that I tried to do json.loads with it when I it's already loaded. All I want is to sort all of these data so it appears properly on web.

How do i properly do this? Do i decode these to json first so it becomes something like

```
{
 "maps":[
         {"id":"blabla","iscategorical":"0"},
         {"id":"blabla","iscategorical":"0"}
        ],
"masks":
         {"id":"valore"},
"om_points":"value",
"parameters":
         {"id":"valore"}
}
```

Then get a value from that using this?

```
data["maps"][0]["id"]  # will return 'blabla'
data["masks"]["id"]    # will return 'valore'
data["om_points"]      # will return 'value'
```

Anyway, I'm confused of what I should do, I tried pretty much everything, these example came from other questions .

Here's a bit of my code:

```
result1 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/2017-11-29/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/', None)
result2 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/2017-11-29/Inspection/Scan-out/Inspector/', None)
print result1["brix"]
```

Firebase is supposed to return a json file. lol but it doesn't work on mine.

Thankyou very much to those who will clear it out to me.

Comment: seems you are receiving Unicode json, try converting it to normal json for parsing via loads function.. else you can try using dumps method.

[refer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954511/convert-unicode-json-to-normal-json-in-python)



Possible Solution in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940272/python-json-loads-returns-items-prefixing-with-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are receiving a Unicode json just as the comment says, if you want the output there's no need to convert to normal function. You can simply do something like this:

```
result1 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/2017-11-29/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/', None)
result2 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/2017-11-29/Inspection/Scan-out/Inspector/', None)
result1 = result1["brix"]["Nov 29, 2017 11:20:15 PM"]["Checklist"]["Luggage bench fabric top is clean"]
```

You will be receiving the

> No

string, without the `'u`

Here's the reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Look at the Decoding JSON part, there's the StringIO import, refer there for more information if you haven't read it yet.