# Remove 'u' in JSON dictionary

Tags: python, json

I hope to use the dictionary load by json file. However, each item contains the character 'u'. I need to remove the 'u's.

I tried dumps, but it does not work.

```
import ast
import json

data= {u'dot',
 u'dog',
 u'fog',
 u'eeee'}

res = eval(json.dumps(data))
print res
```

I hope to get: {
'dot',
'dog',
'fog,
'eeee'
}

But the error is:

> TypeError: set([u'eeee', u'fog', u'dog', u'dot']) is not JSON serializable

Comment: Seems to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954511/convert-unicode-json-to-normal-json-in-python

Comment: The most easy way to "get rid" of the `u` is to upgrade to Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings that start with `u` are unicode strings.

In your case, this has nothing to do with the problem:

```py
data= {u'dot',
 u'dog',
 u'fog',
 u'eeee'}
```

This creates a set and stores the results in the data variable.  The json serializer can't handle sets since the json spec makes no mention of them.  If you change this to be a list, the serializer can handle the data:

```py
res = set(eval(json.dumps(list(data))))
```

Here I'm converting the data variable to a list to serialize it, then converting it back to a set to store the result in the res variable.

Alternatively, you can directly ask Python to convert the unicode strings to strings, using something like this:

```py
res = {x.encode("utf-8") for x in data}
print(res)
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning the unicode conversion from python, as well as giving a detailed answer

Comment: Thanks, it works well for set, when it changes to dictionary, it still not works well, for example:My_Dict = {u'animal': [u'dog',
  u'cat'],
 u'food': [u'rice',
  u'bread',
  u'milk']
 }

some_other_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(My_Dict))
print some_other_dict    (res is:{u'food': [u'rice', u'bread', u'milk'], u'animal': [u'dog', u'cat']})

Comment: More complex types will require more work to parse.  [Here's a simple function](https://pastebin.com/jRZ6Qtn1) to give you an idea of how to parse dicts, sets, or lists in one call.