# Beautifulsoup to extract within tags and output as a JSON

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

As mentioned in the previous question, I am using Beautiful soup with python to retrieve weather data from a website.

Here's how the website looks like:

```
<channel>
<title>2 Hour Forecast</title>
<source>Meteorological Services Singapore</source>
<description>2 Hour Forecast</description>
<item>
<title>Nowcast Table</title>
<category>Singapore Weather Conditions</category>
<forecastIssue date="18-07-2016" time="03:30 PM"/>
<validTime>3.30 pm to 5.30 pm</validTime>
<weatherForecast>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.37500000" lon="103.83900000" name="Ang Mo Kio"/>
<area forecast="SH" lat="1.32100000" lon="103.92400000" name="Bedok"/>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.35077200" lon="103.83900000" name="Bishan"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.30400000" lon="103.70100000" name="Boon Lay"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.35300000" lon="103.75400000" name="Bukit Batok"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.27700000" lon="103.81900000" name="Bukit Merah"/>` 
<channel>
```

I managed to retrieve the information I need using these codes :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import json


weather = []

#getting the time

r = requests.get('http://www.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?dataset=2hr_nowcast&keyref=<keyrefno>')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
time = soup.find('validTime').string
print "validTime: " + time

for currentdate in soup.find_all('item'):
 element = currentdate.find('forecastIssue')
 print "date: " + element['date']

for currentdate in soup.find_all('item'):
 element = currentdate.find('forecastIssue')
 print "time: " + element['time'] 

for area in soup.find('weatherForecast').find_all('area'):
 print area


 #file writing
with open("c:/scripts/nea.json", 'w') as outfile:
json.dumps(weather, outfile)
#outfile.write(",")
```

This is the output I got (in CMD) :

```
C:\scripts>python neaweather.py                                                     
2.30 pm to 4.30 pm                                                              
date: 25-07-2016                                                              
time: 02:30 PM                                                                 
<area forecast="LR" lat="1.37500000" lon="103.83900000" name="Ang Mo Kio"/>   
<area forecast="LR" lat="1.32100000" lon="103.92400000" name="Bedok"/>        
<area forecast="LR" lat="1.35077200" lon="103.83900000" name="Bishan"/>       
<area forecast="LR" lat="1.30400000" lon="103.70100000" name="Boon Lay"/>     
<area forecast="LR" lat="1.35300000" lon="103.75400000" name="Bukit Batok"/>  
<area forecast="LR" lat="1.27700000" lon="103.81900000" name="Bukit Merah"/>
```

I have a few questions that I'm not sure of how to solve :

1. Is there any way to retrieve the attributes in *area forecast="LR" lat="1.37500000" lon="103.83900000" name="Ang Mo Kio"* **without** its tags?

   I tried adding ".text" to my codes but there would always be an error
2. I would like the output to be in a JSON format for my output as it isn't in a table format as shown on tutorials on how to create a JSON file with python :/

**EDIT:** I have managed to open the data in a JSON file but how do I format the unicode string into a normal string as the result contains u' ?

Comment: 1. Your question is not very clear, as `<area forecast="LR" lat="1.37500000" lon="103.83900000" name="Ang Mo Kio"/>` is a single tag (`area`) with many **attributes** (`forecast`, `lat`, `lon`, `name`).

2. Also not very clear. If you want a JSON format you can parse it on your own and create an output in a JSON format..

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I would like to retrieve the attributes of area forecast. Also, may I know how do I parse it in JSON format? Thanks

Comment: You can make use of the attrs property like so: `area_attrs_li = [area.attrs for area in soup.find('weatherForecast').find_all('area')]`

Comment: I used the codes that you provided and the result was : < 'forecast : u'CL'> May I know how do I remove the u?

Comment: Helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940272/python-json-loads-returns-items-prefixing-with-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This in your code:

```
with open("nea.json",'a+') as fs:
    for area in soup.find('weatherForecast').find_all('area'):
        fs.write(str(area.attrs))
```

Comment: Hi, it works! :) but may i know how do I have a line between each attributes in the json file? :)

Comment: just add a "\n" while writing the file, try it.

Comment: Sorry this might sound stupid, but where do I add "\n" at? :x

Comment: `fs.write(str(area.attrs)+"\n")` this will put a line after every line.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to email you the results? There seems to be something wrong with it :/

Comment: sure! bsaraswat45@gmail.com