# Python request .json() method change symbols

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

i will be very appreciated for any help

I'm getting info from website... And generally everyting works fine... But, just look at code:

```
r = requests.get(s_url)
print r.text
>>>[{"nameID":"D1","text":"I’ll understand what actually happened here."}]
print r.json()
>>>[{u'nameID':u'D1',u'text':u'I\u2019ll understand what actually happened 
   here.'"}]
```

As you see after r.json() ' was changed to \u2019.
Why it did it? How I can force to don't make such changes?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940272/python-json-loads-returns-items-prefixing-with-u

Comment: Is the url you are hitting `s_url` returning JSON or plain text?

Comment: @EricWilson s_url return plain text

Comment: Seems you can just use `r.text` then, right? I'm not sure what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an apostrophe (`'`) in your string, but a (unicode) character "right single quotation mark" (`’`). Which may not be as obvious to a naked eye (depending on a font used easier or more difficult to spot), but it is still a completely different character to the computer.

```
>>> u"’" == u"'"
False
```

The difference you see between displaying `text` attributed and what `json()` method returns is just a matter of representation of that character.

For instance:

```
>>> s = u'’'
>>> print s
’
```

But when you do the same with a dictionary returned by `json()` individual keys and values thereof are formatted using `repr()` resulting in:

```
>>> d = {'k': s}
>>> print d
{'k': u'\u2019'}
```

Just as in:

```
>>> print repr(s)
u'\u2019'
```

Nonetheless, it is still the same thing:

```
>>> d['k'] == s
True
```

For that matter:

```
>>> u'’' == u'\u2019'
True
```

You may want to have a look at `__str__()` and `__repr__()` methods as well as description of `print` for more details:

- [https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.**str**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)
- [https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)
- https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#print