# API response array data prefixing with 'u'

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I am receiving the object in the API response - Like the below one:

```
{
    "title": "abc",
    "type": 3,
    "created_at": "2018-10-08T14:04:25",
    "description": "des",
    "data": {
        "response": "[u'9952d1fa', u'ffb1344d', u'a3730337', u'bde08960']"
    }
}
```

Now I want to parse the `response` which is in the data key.
But the `JSON.parse` on the `response` is giving error.

Any idea how to parse this in javascript or should we handle this in the backend (Python-Django)?

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940272/python-json-loads-returns-items-prefixing-with-u) link, but there is no solution in Javascript

Comment: the key:value pairs should be separated by a comma, so that is not a valid JSON

Comment: It's hard to tell how you are generating the response above? It seems like a Python list stringified, and not a JSON result. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you've just logged the response Python has given you and trying to parse that, it's not valid JSON. If you're outputting it programatically to JS then it won't have the `u`'s.

Comment: @fcalderan, I just posted the preview from the network.

Comment: @Jonasm, This is what I am getting from the REST API and yes the backend is in (Python-Django)

Comment: @BenFortune, I want to use the response as an array to loop in. Yes, I am calling the API and saving the result in another object.

Comment: In that case, your backend does not seem to be giving you proper JSON. Or rather it *does* but it's not formatting it as it should - it seems to simply be turning the array into a string representation and posting that which is a valid string but not a valid array in JSON.

Comment: @vlaz, That means I have to update the API response not the handling/parsing.

Comment: @VarunChakervarti it seems like the server is simply wrong, so if you're able to do that, then you should. If you're integrating with a system that is out of your hands and it's doing things incorrectly, you'd have little choice but to follow suit. But if you can make both systems use a valid accepted common format, that is the better way forward.

Comment: Agree with @vlaz

Comment: @vlaz Thank you for your help !!

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky Thank you for your help !!

Comment: I have to change the backend code.

Comment: It isn't an array in the first place @VarunChakervarti. The so-called "array" for which "response" is the key, is actually a string, since it is enclosed in double quotes `" "`,.