# character 'u' in loading json file

Tags: python, json

When I try to load a json file using following code, it gives some u characters:

```
import json

with open('strings.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)

 [{u'goat': 45}, {u'chicken': 45}]
```

what is going on ? any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: json.loads returns items prefixing with 'u'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940272/python-json-loads-returns-items-prefixing-with-u)

Comment: `u` stands for unicode characters

Comment: The u is not a character, it is a prefix.

Comment: The `u` isn't doing any harm. It isn't a part of your data, it is just specifying that your keys are Unicode. When you print a Python data structure (like a list of dicts, as here) you often get a representation that you could use in Python code to recreate that structure. If you want it formatted in a particular way then you need to say how you want it formatted, instead of taking the interpreter's default representation. Simple example: `for k,v in d.items(): print(k,',',v)`.

Answer (score 2):

`u'` is the prefix for Unicode characters

Answer (score 1):

The `u` that you see stands for `unicode`, which is a really common [codification system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) that allows you to manage almost all characters present in all living languages.
It is a good idea to keep your string codified in unicode, but if you want to print out a string without the `u` at the beginning, you can use:

```
print(mystring.encode("utf-8"))
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string) you can follow a SO discussion on the `u` prefix, where someone also cite [this amazing article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) on codification.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use `''` for JSON format. You have to use `""` for JSON format. And You had used `u'something'` Unicode format. No need to use Unicode in this section. Sometime need to encode `b''` for Binary.

So your code look like

```
import json

with open('strings.json', encoding("utf-8")) as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)

   #[{"goat": 45},{"chicken": 45}]
```