# Iterate over json and parse key value pair

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse key value pairs(fname and jobcode) after performing get request.
What's the best way to parse key value pairs to perform tasks?

Below is my get request response on

```
response = requests.get('url')
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "fname": "James",
        "jobcode": "51202"
    },
    {
        "fname": "Jim",
        "jobcode": "32304"
    }
]
```

Tried it this way, and got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`.

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print json_data
for key, value in json_data.items():
    print key, value
```

I want to translate it into a list like `[James, 51202], [Jim, 32304]` so that I can easily use. Or, I'd like to just get key value pairs so that I can iterate over them.

Comment: It's nothing to do with JSON. You have a list and dictionaries inside it.

Comment: The loads function, will return you a list with a name and a dictionary, user `json_data[1].items()`

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that:

```
response = [
    {
        "fname": "James",
        "jobcode": "51202"
    },
    {
        "fname": "Jim",
        "jobcode": "32304"
    }
]
```

If you want to couple the elements in the dictionary you can do:

```
listdata = [[el[1] for el in dd.items()] for dd in response]
```

`listdata` is `[['James', '51202'], ['Jim', '32304']]`

Or if you prefer a plain list (no nested lists) with all the data:

```
listdata = [el[1] for dd in response for el in dd.items()]
```

In this case `listdata` is `['James', '51202', 'Jim', '32304']`.

Comment: Why do I get [u'James'], [u'51202'] ?

Comment: Because your strings are unicode (that is the meaning of the 'u' before the string). In general is not a problem, the 'u' is there in the string representation to specify that is a unicode string. But the string itself does not have any prefixed u (for example, if you write the string back in a file, there is no 'u'). Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940272/python-json-loads-returns-items-prefixing-with-u) too.