# python how to write each line as a file

Tags: python

I have a JSON file which is 5 lines long. I want to write each line to a seperate file, i.e write `line1` to `file1`, `line2` to `file2` etc

Now, I am trying to write the file in a file, but data is in a line and disorder, and there is a weird 'u' before each key and value on the writing file.

```py
import json

with open("test1.json") as f:
    with open("1.json","w") as o:
        lines = f.readline()
        for line in lines:
            y =  json.loads(line)
            print(y)
            json.dump(y,o)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940272/python-json-loads-returns-items-prefixing-with-u

Comment: properly written `json` file usually has 1 line, what you do is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

```
   linecount = 0 
   with open("test1.json") as f:
        lines = f.readline()
        for line in lines:
            linecount = linecount + 1
            with open(str(linecount)+".json","w") as o:
                y =  json.loads(line)
                print(y)
                o.writelines(y)
```

**Updated**: added @tripleee suggestion

```
fp = open("test1.json",'r')
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    with open(str(i)+".json","w") as o:
        y =  json.loads(line)
        print(y)
        o.writelines(y)
```

Everything looks good in your code except this line `with open("1.json","w") as o:`
change this line to create new file for each line

logic is - Count the line, Create file with linecount.json and dump the json

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way to do this would be:

```py
with open('test1.json').readlines() as json_data:  # readlines returns a list containing each line as seperate items
    for i in range(len(json_data)):  # For loop allows this to work with any number of lines
        file = open(f'{str(i+1)}.json', 'w')  # Same as '{str(i+1)}.json'.format() or str(i+1)+'.json'
        file.write(json_data[i])
        file.close()
        # print(json.loads(json_data[i]) # Uncomment if you want to print the content of each line
```

This allows you to work with any number of lines - dynamically  naming the output file for you.

The `u` in front of the strings (like `u'string'`) means unicode string. This is now a deprecated inclusion of the python language - the defualt string type is unicode. It is now only in python 3 for compatibility with python 2.

(source: [What's the u prefix in a Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464959/whats-the-u-prefix-in-a-python-string/2464968))